# Cannot Install NVENC SDK 5.0

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

I would like to install NVENC SDK 5.0 in Ubuntu 14.04. I don't know how to install it. After downloading the file, I applied 'make' command in /nvenc_5.0.1_sdk/Samples/NvEncoder directory.

The output:

```
g++ -m64 -o NvEncoder NvHWEncoder.o NvEncoder.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -L/usr/lib64 -lnvidia-encode -ldl 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libnvidia-encode.so when searching for -lnvidia-encode
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libnvidia-encode.so when searching for -lnvidia-encode
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../libnvidia-encode.so when searching for -lnvidia-encode
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libnvidia-encode.so when searching for -lnvidia-encode
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnvidia-encode
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [NvEncoder] Error 1
```

I understand that it cannot find libnvenc-encode.so file in /usr/lib64 directory. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think what we got is just sample code. libnvidia-encode.so and libvcuvid.so are contained in nvidia's driver package. After install `cuda` which install `nvidia-352` driver for me, i got `/usr/lib/nvidia-352` directory, under where i find libnvidia-encode.so. Try to use `locate libnvidia-encode.so` to find where it is after run `sudo updatedb`.

By the way you can use `make` to autocomplie the sample code instead of type `g++` yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this manual](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/ffmpeg/1511-patch/FFMPEG-with-NVIDIA-Acceleration-on-Ubuntu_UG_v01.pdf) from "step-by-step and installation" part.